# ManagementEventWatcher Stop/Start/Disposing issues

Tags: c#, wmi, managementeventwatcher

I got really annoying issue here.. Consider following code:

```
private static void _KindlePlugedEventWatcher_EventArrived(
        object sender,
        EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var plugedLogicalDisk = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];
        if ((plugedLogicalDisk["VolumeName"] as string) == _KindleName)
        {

            var kindleID = plugedLogicalDisk["DeviceID"] as string; // logical letter, like "F:"
            if (kindleID.IsNotNull() &&

                /* somewhy this event fires two times in a sequence,
                thus it is necessary to check,
                if such kindleID is already present 
                in the list of pluged devices;

                because of async sequence Pause() and Resume() 
                are necessary...*/
                !(PlugedDevices.HasItem(
                    (kindleDevice) => { return kindleDevice.ID == kindleID ? true : false; }
                )))

            {
                PauseListening();
                App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                    async () =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var kindleDevice = await KindleDevice.Create(kindleID);
                            PlugedDevices.Add(kindleDevice);
                        }

                        catch (FileNotFoundException)
                        {
                            /* means that Kindle might not has 
                            'My Clippings.txt' at all,
                            or some IO melfunction happened */

                            throw;
                        }


                    });
                ResumeListening();
            }
        }
    }
```

Both `Pause...()` and `Resume...()`are just simple wrappers around Stop()/Start() methods, provided by MEW class. Well, that does not work at all. Even if I use to DETACH handling methods (`-= _KindlePlugedEventWatcher_EventArrived`)... IT KEEPS FIRING SECOND TIME. Moreover, I have tried calling Dispose(). IT DOESNT HELP: MEW OBJECT STILL LIVING!!!

Does someone have an idea?